# How to get FirstName of customer from @WorkContext.CurrentUser - Orchards CMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I am using Orchards CMS system to build my website and I have some code below:

```
@T("Hello"), 
<a href="@Url.Action("ViewCustomer", "Checkout", 
                                           new { area = "Skywalker.Webshop" })">
@WorkContext.CurrentUser.UserName
</a>
```

It's display the userName of customer on View.

Now I want display FirstName of the customer But I don't know How to do?

I used Module Skywalker.Webshop on my project.

Answer (score 4):

I would assume there is a part attached to user with first name in it but I don't know what the part is called.

```
@WorkContext.CurrentUser.As<PersonPart>().FirstName
```

So replace "PersonPart" with whatever part you have attached to user